# Read text of a control that is not shown under Visible Text using AutoIt Window Info tool

Tags: autoit

I have a window inside which I have a Control. I can read the Class and Instance of this control using **AutoIt Window Info Tool**, but the Visible Text column does not display the text that is visible inside this control. Hence, I am not able to read the text using `ControlGetText` Function. Is there any other way to read this text? All I want to do is read the text that is being displayed under this control.

This is the info that I am getting in AutoIt Window Info. I can see a text "Sample text" in the control, but it's not available in the Visible Text tab

[image]

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  Documents
Class:  CabinetWClass
Position:   80, 77
Size:   1355, 744
Style:  0x14CF0000
ExStyle:    0x00000100
Handle: 0x0000000000310B4A

>>>> Control <<<<
Class:  Internet Explorer_Server
Instance:   1
ClassnameNN:    Internet Explorer_Server1
Name:   
Advanced (Class):   [CLASS:Internet Explorer_Server; INSTANCE:1]
ID: 
Text:   
Position:   794, 87
Size:   545, 566
ControlClick Coords:    255, 174
Style:  0x56000000
ExStyle:    0x00000000
Handle: 0x0000000000BA08A2

>>>> Mouse <<<<
Position:   1137, 368
Cursor ID:  0
Color:  0xFFFFFF

>>>> StatusBar <<<<
1:  

>>>> ToolsBar <<<<

>>>> Visible Text <<<<
Address: C:\Users\some\path
Documents
Shell Preview Extension Host
Namespace Tree Control
Tree View
ShellView


>>>> Hidden Text <<<<
Namespace Tree Control
```

Comment: And what does the Hidden Text field show?

Comment: It's not a Hidden Text field. If I open the window, I can see the text inside the control. But if I place the finder tool on this control using "AutoIt Window Info" I am not able to see the text under "Visible Text" tab of the "AutoIt Window Info" tool. i.e I get empty text returned when I use ControlGetText on this control.

Comment: Any chance you can post some of your code? That will help you with a solution, since we can't say that `ControlGetText` is working or not because we don't know how you are using it in your code.

Comment: ControlGetText will only return if we can see the text in the "Visible Text" tab of "AutoIt Window Info". Since the text itself is not shown there, ControlGetText will not fetch anything. Hence, there is no way that ControlGetText is working incorrectly. I hope this clears up things a bit.

Comment: What program are you getting the information from if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I have added an image

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it looks like it's showing you the visible text.. Wasn't your question on getting the visible text?

Comment: From your cut image I personally can not see which application you are trying to automate.
Post some code you tried or the Summary of the autoit info tool.
I would also recommend you try also Spy++ to see if that would give you more information than autoit info tool.

Comment: Let me repeat my question:
What does the Hidden text tab o the AutoItWindowInfo shows?

Comment: The Hidden text field also does not show the text that I want

Comment: The hidden text shows HIDDEN TEXT. Which means a text that is not visible on the controlID. If you see your text then if you can't find it at the hidden text tab of te autoit info tool then it is not a hidden text. However I am sure that you can read that text. Post the summary and we might help you a little bit more.

Comment: Then you'll need to figure out how to put "hidden text" in this program that you won't tell us.

Comment: It's not a hidden text. It's simply not available directly under Visible Text or Hidden Text and I am looking for some alternate way (like finding children of the current control, etc) to reach the text. I have pasted the summary as asked by @user2530266

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. After looking through the AutoIt forum for an hour or so, I have found many people trying to do the same thing you are. None of them have found a solution. Have you tried `Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1)` 0=no, 1=search children?

Comment: Can you also post a pic of your entire window with the text you are trying to read? It would be good if we could test it...

Comment: Sorry I can't because of security policies at the place where I work

Comment: Well then i can not help you, maybe someone else can. Good luck.
P.S. I think your autoit info tool summary is modified ;)

Comment: Only Address field has been modified, which is of no use anyways to find a solution to this problem

Comment: The only way anyone is going to be able to help you, is to see what window you are trying to pull information from. Without that, we can't know if there is human error or if the program needs certain interaction involved. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The control you are accessing is embed object instance of Internet Explorer.
In order to attach to it, you can use _IEAttach using the mode "embedded".

```
; Attach to a browser control embedded in another window

#include <IE.au3>

Local $oIE = _IEAttach("A Window Title", "embedded")
Local $sText = _IEBodyReadText($oIE)
MsgBox(0, "Body Text", $sText)
```